# html5 video background

Tags: html, video, background

I use video background in this site onemindlive.com
I use loop. But when the video ends before the restart 
going short pause.
Why it does not work continuously without stopping?

```
.landing-video {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.landing-video__image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

<div class="landing-video">
  <video class="landing-video__image" poster="landing_video_background.jpg" autoplay loop muted>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="landing_video_background.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding a preload attribute should help with that. The pause (from what I saw) is the video "rewinding".

Comment: I added preload="auto", but it doesn't work. After 15 seconds when the video rewinding again i see small pause (in chrome)